# Python version of freopen()

Tags: c++, python, c, file, file-io

Is there anything in python that can replicate the functionality of freopen() in C or C++? To be precise, I want to replicate the functionality of:

```
freopen("input.txt","r",stdin);
```

and

```
freopen("output.txt","w",stdout);
```

And then use the same (standard) functions for console I/O for file I/O. Any ideas?

Comment: related: [Redirect stdout to a file in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4675728/4279)

Answer (score 10):

`sys.stdout` is simply `file` object, so, you can reopen it to another destination

```
out = sys.stdout
sys.stdout = open('output.txt', 'w')
// do some work
sys.stdout = out
```

`out` is only for recovering `sys.stdout` destination to default after work (as suggested Martijn Pieters - you can recover it by using `sys.__stdout__`, or not recover at all, if you don't need it).

Comment: @Quixotic yes, sys.stdin and 'r'

Comment: Also a good idea to have `old = sys.stdout` in case you need it again

Comment: @jamylak: Note that there is also `sys.__stdout__`, holding the default, so you can restore from that.

Comment: @MartijnPieters much better idea, unless `sys.stdout` has already been changed but that's unlikely

Answer (score 8):

Try this:

```
import sys
sys.stdin = open('input.txt', 'r') 
sys.stdout = open('output.txt', 'w')
```

Text files are self explanatory.
You can now run this code on Sublime Text or any other text editor.

Comment: @Vasilis does't works for input with spaces in between. Eg 4 6. Help

Comment: @Anuj hello there, I think you need to ping Kushagra Kukreja who posted the answer above on this one.

Answer (score 6):

If you're working on *nix platform, you can write your own `freopen`.

```
def freopen(f,option,stream):
    import os
    oldf = open(f,option)
    oldfd = oldf.fileno()
    newfd = stream.fileno()
    os.close(newfd)
    os.dup2(oldfd, newfd)

import sys
freopen("hello","w",sys.stdout)

print "world"
```

Comment: As specified in POSIX, [`dup2` will close `newfd` if it is already open](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/dup.html). In fact, it's better not to close `newfd` explicitly first, since `dup2` guarantees that the close-and-reuse happens atomically.

Answer (score 4):

You may also want to look at the `contextmanager` decorator in [`contextlib`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/contextlib.html) for temporary redirection:

```
from contextlib import contextmanager 
import sys 

@contextmanager
def stdout_redirected(new_stdout):
    save_stdout = sys.stdout
    sys.stdout  = new_stdout
    try:
        yield
    finally:
        sys.stdout = save_stdout
```

Example:

```
 with open(filename, "w") as f:
     with stdout_redirected(f):
         print "Hello"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should help:

```
import sys

def freopen(filename, mode):
    if mode == "r":
        sys.stdin = open(filename, mode)

    elif mode == "w":
        sys.stdout = open(filename, mode)

# ---- MAIN ----

freopen("input.txt", "r")
freopen("output.txt", "w")
```